# I want to deploy node app with socket listen 8001 on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, localhost

I want to deploy node app on heroku, the web will send post request to another backend server, this part is ok. 

But node app is WEB UI package I got it from someone, there is a socket inside, which is `http://localhost:8001`, 

the socket will listen 8001. This part is ok when I run the WEB UI on my mac, 
but on heroku, this connection has problem. 

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: This is basic Heroku stuff. Please see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#common-runtime-networking and the [getting started documentation for your language](https://devcenter.heroku.com/start). If you're still confused feel free to post again but make sure to include a [mcve] so we can help you. The [ask] page has some good tips about asking questions effectively.

Comment: the doc says "Individual processes within a dyno can bind to any address or port they want and communicate among them using e.g. standard TCP" but I don't know how to do it. This part is the link between the web and outsides world.
var port = normalizePort( '3001');
app.set('port', port); But in another file :                                                                
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001'); and another file var conn = function() {
    server.listen(8001);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
};

Comment: That's _within one single dyno_. Do you see what it says about the `PORT` environment variable?